# How to reset Sourcetree settings/preferences

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I've done something nasty in my preferences! Is there any way I can reset Sourcetree to default settings?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could see if the process describe in [Wiping SourceTree Preferences](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html) can help - but be careful:

> Please note that wiping the preferences will mean you will **lose your bookmarks and view settings**.
> Please back these up in the event that wiping your preferences isn't the cause of the problem.

#### Windows

> - Make sure SourceTree is closed
> - Make sure the files are backed up in the following folders before removing the files
> - Remove files "`bookmarks.xml`", "`opentabs.xml`", "`userhosts`" in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\`
> - Remove file in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe<random_string>\<version_number>\user.config`
> - Open SourceTree again to test if it worked or not.

#### Mac

> - Make sure SourceTree is closed.
> - Make sure the files are backed up in the following folders before removing the files
> - Remove everything in `~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree/`
> - Remove `~/Library/Preferences/com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS.plist` (you should be using the direct version of SourceTree, hence "NotMAS")
> - If you're using Mavericks or later, log out and log back in. Mavericks caches all Preferences while you're logged in and deleting the files doesn't actually clear the settings any more.
> - Open SourceTree again to test if it worked or not.

(Those are **hidden** folders/files: you can [look for them in Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391893))

[...]

> If this didn't fix your problems then close SourceTree and restore the files, then re-open SourceTree again (if at all possible).

---

Update 2018: [Skychan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975019/skychan) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163023/how-to-reset-sourcetree-settings-preferences/24163139?noredirect=1#comment88153842_24163139)

> With the [current version, 2.7+](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-Release-Notes-for-Current-Version/qaq-p/630377) you need to also delete (backup) the two `.json` files in the `\Atlassian\SourceTree\` directory.

(On MacOS: `/Applications/SourceTree.app/`)

Comment: With the current version you need to also delete (backup) the two .json files in the \Atlassian\SourceTree\ directory.

Comment: Not clear where '\Atlassian\SourceTree\' is such directory on Mac.

Comment: @Jonauz https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-embedded-git-or-system-git-in-sourcetree-785323587.html suggests `/Applications/SourceTree.app/`, as in `/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/bin`

Comment: The Mac solution doesn't work anymore even after logging out and deleting the files/folders in the answer.

Comment: @proteus OK. Let me know if you find a workaround/solution, I will update the answer.

Comment: These files do not exist on my mac

Comment: @BrianReinhold Which, seven years later, is not too surprising. Do you find a  `SourceTree.app` folder anywhere on yuor Mac? Which OS version do you have?

Comment: @VonC I found the app but not all the supplemental files it generates. Turns out they are hidden and the only way I can view them is via a Terminal using ls -a. I am a total greenhorn on the Mac and assumed I could use the Finder to see hidden files in the same manner I use the Windows File Explorer to see hidden files. Alas such is not the case. I wish the mac had Tortoise git!

Comment: @BrianReinhold I agree. But looking for hidden files with finder should be possible though: https://setapp.com/how-to/show-hidden-files-on-mac#:~:text=See%20hidden%20files%20on%20Mac%20via%20Finder&text=In%20Finder%2C%20open%20up%20your,2%20to%20hide%20them%20again and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391893

Comment: @VonC good to know keyboard combos are needed - I looked for the option through the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

> - Make sure the files are backed up in the following folders before
>     removing the files Remove files `"bookmarks.xml"`, `"opentabs.xml"`,
>     `"userhosts"` in
>     `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\`
> - Remove file in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe<random_string>\<version_number>\user.config`
>     Open SourceTree again to test if it worked or not.

I was having a problem with authentication (username and password), so I needed to reset my account. I follow all those steps for Windows, but I´m also deleted the `passwd` file, now everything is ok :)

Comment: With the current version you need to also delete (backup) the two .json files in the \Atlassian\SourceTree\ directory.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the following steps:

1. [Wipe SourceTree preferences](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html).
2. Uninstall SourceTree (if it shows on the App&Features list)
3. Backup then delete the directory below before proceeding with next
   step

   - Navigate to C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local and delete SourceTree & SourceTree-Settings folder
   - Navigate to C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local\Atlassian and delete all SourceTree Files/Folder.
4. Download SourceTree and install it.

Comment: How is this different from the "Windows" section of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24163139/6309)? https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html is the very first link I have in my aforementioned answer.

Comment: you're right Vonc, but i am here guiding about if some one want to remove complete folders not only sub folder, because i was facing the issue so i solved by this.

Answer (score -1):

I was having a problem with authentication (username and password), so I needed to reset my account. I follow all those steps for Windows, but I´m also deleted the passwd file, now everything is ok

Below steps: worked
Make sure the files are backed up in the following folders before removing the files Remove files "bookmarks.xml", "opentabs.xml", "userhosts" in C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree
Remove file in C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe<random_string><version_number>\user.config Open SourceTree again to test if it worked or not.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34373690)